# Integrate django auth with Nodejs passport authentication?

Tags: django, node.js, mongodb, authentication, passport.js

I have django app  that is using postgresql as a backend. It have different authentication method and this app running on server **A** .

setting.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'login',
    'reports',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'reporting.urls'

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_PATH],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'reporting.wsgi.application'
```

and my second application is on Nodejs with backend mongoDB and authentication method is passport-local. It is running on server **B**

primary app is Django.

Now I want If Login from django app and click to link that directly go to Nodejs app without login.

Or any other method for login in both application with single authentication.